# How to find the most frequent prefix of the set length n?

Tags: java, prefix, trie

I'm writing a Trie structure. How can I find the most frequent prefix of the set length n and the most frequent prefix of the length n or longer?

I've found this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2794381/getting-a-list-of-words-from-a-trie/32452073#32452073) useful to get all the words which start with set prefix.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow ! What did you try ? Using a tree seems to be a good idea here.

Comment: Add a counter to the trie nodes. Increment the counter as you build the trie. Then scan the nodes afterwards to examine the counters.

Comment: Yes, it works now :) Thanks

Comment: The most frequent prefix of length n or longer is the most frequent prefix of length n, except if you attempt to find the longest prefix among the most frequent prefixes of length n or longer.