# Implementing pattern matching in a trie tree

Tags: java, string, data-structures, pattern-matching, trie

I am currently using a trie implementation from this stack overflow post:

[Getting a list of words from a Trie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2794381/getting-a-list-of-words-from-a-trie)

to return a list of words which match a given prefix. I'm then using regex to filter out the words which don't meet the entire specified pattern.

EX: if the pattern I'm searching for is: CH??S? and this is a subset of the dictionary which matches my initial prefix:
 {CHABAD, CHACHA, CHARIOT, CHATTED, CHEATER, CHOMSKY, CHANNEL CHAFED, CHAFER, CHAINS, CHAIRS, CHEESE, CHEESY CHRONO, CHUTES, CHISEL}

I would search the trie with 'CH' prefix and then filter out words which match my desired pattern of CH??S? (CHEESY, CHEESE, CHISEL) and return those.

I am wondering if there is a faster way to do this to avoid using the regex in the final step. I thought I could use a suffix tree ([Ukkonen's suffix tree algorithm in plain English](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452701/ukkonens-suffix-tree-algorithm-in-plain-english) )or the boyer-moore algorithm but neither work because they search on suffixes not on patterns.

Comment: Can you turn your prefix search into a suffix search?  For `CH??S?` search for `CH??` and then search for all of those plus `S?`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a nice recursive algorithm you can use that eliminates the need to use a final regex pass. It works by matching a pattern P against a tree T:

```
FindMatches(pattern P, tree T) {
    if (tree is empty) {
        return that there are no matches;
    }

    if (pattern is empty) {
        report a match if T is a word;
    } else if (pattern[0] is a letter) {
        FindMatches(P[1:], T.childFor(pattern[0]));
    } else if (pattern[0] is ?) {
        for (each child C of T) {
             gather matches from FindMatches(P[1:], C);
        }
        report all matches found this way;
    } else {
        something is wrong with your pattern;
    }
}
```

Your approach of just matching `CH` follows along with this approach. However, when you get to the point where you're matching `?` characters, your approach just does a DFS to find all words below the current point, whereas this approach instead just branches on one level and gathers up matches. Stated differently, this approach is a hybrid between "follow one character at a time if there's a clear character to follow" and "explore the whole subtree looking for matches," focusing the branching strategically.